# Maven-properties-filtering-like for Java annotations?

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties, filtering

Currently, I know how to do this kind of filtering using Maven:

*pom.xml*

```xml
<properties>
    <foo>bar</foo>
</properties>
```

*app.properties*

```
foo=${foo}
```

But is it possible to do that kind of filtering, using Maven, Spring or any tool else?

*MyClass.java*

```java
@MyAnnotation("${foo}") // ${foo} should get replaced at compile time
public void getData() {
    return data;
}
```

Comment: you could use maven resource filtering on your source files at the generate-sources phase - place your *.java files under some non-source directory (better not use /resources), and in that phase copy them over to the generated sources directory

Comment: This would mean your annotation would have to have `SOURCE` retention policy for one. And you want to patch source code to boot? Good luck :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using an execution of the resource plugin.  You can point it at your Java source and use its normal filtering, as far as I know.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

```
  <properties>
    <my.name>chad</my.name>
    <java.property>//comment</java.property>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>target/processed-source/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>

         <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>../processed-source/java</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>

  </build>
```

So, the first thing is that you route the processed java source into a special folder in the target directory.  Next, you have to reconfigure the compiler plugin to NOT compile the unfiltered source, and, instead, compile the new source. Note, as with all things maven, you can configure a lot more than this.

This [blog entry](https://connect.gxsoftware.com/Blogs/Bram-de-Kruijff/Maven-secrets-filtering-sources.htm) is useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't make it working, even if I specify the `targetPath` Maven attribute. In fact, I never tried using *.java source files, do you have any working example?